# locked out of wordpress site 'warning: require once'

Tags: fatal-error, warnings

my site "puncturecallout.com" is not appearing and I cannot access the admin login page either. the error reads:

Warning: require_once(/home1/mytenni5/public_html/puncturecallout/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/includes/class-wc-gateway-ppec-with-paypal-credit.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/mytenni5/public_html/puncturecallout/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/includes/class-wc-gateway-ppec-gateway-loader.php on line 22

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home1/mytenni5/public_html/puncturecallout/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/includes/class-wc-gateway-ppec-with-paypal-credit.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php70/lib/php') in /home1/mytenni5/public_html/puncturecallout/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/includes/class-wc-gateway-ppec-gateway-loader.php on line 22

any help much appreciated
regards
Robbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the log says, a file is missing. If you FTP in to your site (or use your host's File Manager, if they offer one) you can change the name of the folder currently called `/wp-content/plugins/` - i.e. change it to something like `/wp-content/oldplugins/`. That should then allow you to log in.

Once you log in, you can rename the folder back to its original name and reactivate your plugins one by one. If there is still a problem with a missing file WP will prevent the plugin from being activated, and you can download the plugin from its original source and upload it via FTP/File Manager if needed.

Comment: You could have also just renamed the offending plugin folder: woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout , which was causing the error. Then use that plugin's support area to resolve your problem.